How to customize Mat-Tabs?
i'm trying to customize the color of inactive mat-tabs but i can't find documentation to find the exact rule to use. I tried other answers but they are old and doesn't apply to my case.
i found an answer with this rules:
    .mat-mdc-tab-group,
    .mat-mdc-tab-nav-bar {
  --mat-tab-header-active-focus-label-text-color: #151414;
  --mat-tab-header-active-label-text-color: #151414;
  --mat-tab-header-inactive-label-text-color: rgb(0 0 0 / 60%);
  --mat-tab-header-inactive-focus-label-text-color: rgb(236 131 218 / 60%);
  --mat-tab-header-inactive-hover-label-text-color: rgb(236 131 218 / 60%);
  --mdc-tab-indicator-active-indicator-color: #242022;
  --mat-tab-header-active-hover-label-text-color: #5052c3;
  --mat-tab-header-active-ripple-color: #c2185b;
  --mat-tab-header-inactive-ripple-color: #232222;
}

it works but i don't see the rule to change the background color of inactive tabs.
Is there a way to find the full list?

If you inspect css of mat tabs you'll see these css variables that are configurable
.mat-primary.mat-mdc-tab-group,.mat-primary.mat-mdc-tab-nav-bar {
    --mdc-tab-indicator-active-indicator-color: #005cbb;
    --mat-tab-header-divider-color: #e0e2ec;
    --mat-tab-header-pagination-icon-color: #1a1b1f;
    --mat-tab-header-inactive-label-text-color: #1a1b1f;
    --mat-tab-header-active-label-text-color: #1a1b1f;
    --mat-tab-header-active-ripple-color: #1a1b1f;
    --mat-tab-header-inactive-ripple-color: #1a1b1f;
    --mat-tab-header-inactive-focus-label-text-color: #1a1b1f;
    --mat-tab-header-inactive-hover-label-text-color: #1a1b1f;
    --mat-tab-header-active-focus-label-text-color: #1a1b1f;
    --mat-tab-header-active-hover-label-text-color: #1a1b1f;
    --mat-tab-header-active-focus-indicator-color: #005cbb;
    --mat-tab-header-active-hover-indicator-color: #005cbb
}

Background color is hardcoded as none in there css. I suppose it's just a material spec of how it should be with transparent background.
So if you need such customisations then you should just define a global styles for your case like this
/* default background for all tab headers */
.mdc-tab { 
    background: red;
}

/* override default background for active tabs */
.mdc-tab.mdc-tab--active {
    background: blue;
}

As a result you will have red inactive tabs and blue active tabs

upd:
for local component style changes there are two ways of doing this.

is more clean but makes a global style that will place your css code into main bundle rather than lazy load with your component:
add custom classname in html

<mat-tab-group class="my-custom-tabs">

add global styles:
/* default background for all tab headers */
.my-custom-tabs .mdc-tab { 
    background: red;
}

/* override default background for active tabs */
.my-custom-tabs .mdc-tab.mdc-tab--active {
    background: blue;
}


use ::ng-deep, not that clean because it is meant to be deprecated feature. But doesn't seem to be ever removed it feels because lots of project depend on this feature in sometimes it critical to use it to make things work

In your component's styles:
:host ::ng-deep {
  .mdc-tab { 
      background: red;
  }
 
  .mdc-tab.mdc-tab--active {
      background: blue;
  }
}


Thank you for helping me, i tried this but it only applies in the style.css globally and not inside the component's css. I need it only for a specific tab group

made an update section in my answer for your case
